# Audio stops instantly after loading next scene

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-development

I'm new in unity, cannot solve a problem. I have a sound and a script. On collision it should play the sound and it does so but it also loads next scene and isntantly stops the sound.

here's my code

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ScoreCounter : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject Step;
    public int scoreCounter;
    public float speedGain = 0f; //-026f
    private AudioSource audioSource;
    public AudioClip Scored;

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        scoreCounter++;
        if (scoreCounter == 1)
        {
            speedGain = -0.235f;
        }
        if (collision.name == "gates")
        {
            scoreCounter -= 1;
            audioSource = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
            audioSource.clip = Scored;
            audioSource.Play();
        }
        speedGain -= 0.025f;
        Instantiate(Step, new Vector2(0.0f, 5.0f), Quaternion.identity);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unity automatically stops your sound because your audioSource is being **Disabled** when you start or load a new scene.

You can avoid this by using some plugins like **FMOD** but I will suggest the `DontDestroyOnLoad()` to avoid having this problem and it's an easy fix.

Firstly put the audioSource in an empty gameObject and use your script with it and add a random tag for it, like "audioObj".
Then you need to call the `DontDestroyOnLoad()` in the `Awake`of the script attached to it:

```
private void Awake()
 {
     DontDestroyOnLoad(transform.gameObject);
     audioSource = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
 }
```

In this way, you can start playing music from all the scenes without having problems or the music to stop with this simple line:

```
GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("audioObj").GetComponent<AudioScript>().PlayMusic();
```

And also

```
GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("audioObj").GetComponent<AudioScript>().StopMusic();
```

Where AudioScript is the script of your audio and `PlayMusic()` and `StopMusic()` are public functions that play and stop music, but you can do it with everything, you just need to call the `GameObjec.FindGameObjectWithTag("audioObj");`

Hope I helped!